# How to set a data by default in a drop-down list

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

In a project symfony3.4, I have tow entitys : Personne and Nationalite

In my form drop-down list I want select by default Nationalite 'French'.

PersonneType.php:

```
...
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('nationalite', EntityType::class, array(
                        'class' => 'AppBundle:Nationalite',
                        'choice_label' => 'libelle',
                        'required' => false,
                        'empty_data' => function(NationaliteRepository $repo) {
                            return $repo->getNationaliteParDefaut();
                        }
                    ))
->add...
```

In NationaliteRepository.php:

```
...
    public function getNationaliteParDefaut(){
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('n');
        $qb->where($qb->expr()->eq('n.codeInsee', ':code_insee'))
            ->setParameter('code_insee', 99100); //99100 is France code_insee
        return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();

    }
...
```

This methode generate the following error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   AppBundle\Form\PersonneType::AppBundle\Form{closure}() must be an
>   instance of AppBundle\Repository\NationaliteRepository, instance of
>   Symfony\Component\Form\Form given, called in /var/www/...vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php on line 620 and defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way for entities/objects is to set the default option on the object class itself, either in the entity itself or before form creation, or using some builder/factory.

```php
// let say thisis the class which will be filled with the natinalite
Class Person  {
   private $name
   // ... some other fields ...
   private $nationalite

   public function setNationalite(Nationalite $nationale) 
   {
      $this->nationalite = $nationalite
   }
}
```

**Form creation object method**

```php
$person = new Person();
$person->setNationalite($repo->getNationaliteParDefaut());
// lets say personType is your form, that also has field nationalite
$form = $this->createForm(PersonType:class, $person);
```

With this setup the form will be prepopulated with default data, from the object, including nationalite, and the user can still easilily change it.

**Non object method**
Another way of doing what you want is using form events.

```
// in your form definition
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) {
   $form = $event->getForm();
   $data = $event->getData();
   $form->add('nationalite', EntityType::class, array(
       'class' => 'AppBundle:Nationalite',
       'choice_label' => 'libelle',
       'required' => false,
       'data' => $repo->getNationaliteParDefaut()
   )
}
```

**About `empty_data`**
Empty data only works if the the form field is empty, eg. the user didn't select anything so the value from empty data will be used
ref: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#empty-data

Comment: $person->setNationalite($repo->getNationaliteParDefaut()); // Where / How to recover the $repo variable?

Comment: I solved that by doing:

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        
        $personne = $options['data'];
        $em = $options['entityManager'];
        $defaultNationalite = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Nationalite')->getNationaliteParDefaut();
        
        if(is_null($personne->getNationalite())){
            $personne->setNationalite($defaultNationalite);
        }
-------------
see : https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/form_dependencies.html

Comment: $person->setNationalite($repo->getNationaliteParDefaut()).  
Usually you call createForm in controller, so you can dependency inject your repository or entity manager there and call the method.  

This is somehow related: https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#rendering-forms.  

On top of that example you just need to inject your repository and set data to your form object

Answer (score 0):

Try preferred_choices option https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/types/entity.html#preferred-choices . The preferred_choices appear on top of the list but won't be selected. If you want an item selected, build the form with a POPO (Plain Object PHP Object) with the default nationality you want.

Comment: "  If you want an item selected, build the form with a POPO " // 
I do not know how to do {o_O}